# Can't access secret in GCP Secret Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to migrate my code from using API keys stored in the `.env` file to using Google Cloud Platform Secrets Manager. I've followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#command-line) but I encounter an error saying that I don't have permissions to access the secret.

```js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"
import { SecretManagerServiceClient } from "@google-cloud/secret-manager"

admin.initializeApp()
const secretClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient()

async function main() {
  async function getSecret(): Promise<string | null | undefined> {
    const [version] = await secretClient.accessSecretVersion({ name: "TELEGRAM_TOKEN" })

    return version.payload?.data?.toString()
  }

  const TELEGRAM_TOKEN = await getSecret()
  console.log(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
}

main().catch(console.error)
```

And that's the error I get:

```
> node lib/app.js --telegram

{ Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on resource project TELEGRAM_TOKEN.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/Users/bartekpacia/dev/node/telegram-lang-enforcer/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/bartekpacia/dev/node/telegram-lang-enforcer/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:174:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/bartekpacia/dev/node/telegram-lang-enforcer/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:340:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/bartekpacia/dev/node/telegram-lang-enforcer/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:303:181)
    at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (/Users/bartekpacia/dev/node/telegram-lang-enforcer/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:114:27)
    at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (/Users/bartekpacia/dev/node/telegram-lang-enforcer/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:153:22)
    at Http2CallStream.endCall (/Users/bartekpacia/dev/node/telegram-lang-enforcer/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:140:18)
    at Http2CallStream.handleTrailers (/Users/bartekpacia/dev/node/telegram-lang-enforcer/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:262:14)
    at ClientHttp2Stream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emit (internal/http2/core.js:265:8)
  code: 7,
  details: 'Permission denied on resource project TELEGRAM_TOKEN.',
  metadata:
   Metadata {
     internalRepr:
      Map {
        'google.rpc.help-bin' => [Array],
        'grpc-status-details-bin' => [Array],
        'grpc-server-stats-bin' => [Array] },
     options: {} },
  note:
   'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient' }
```

I did create a Service Account with "Owner" permissions, downloaded it and made `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/...`. My service account .json file location is correctly displayed when I execute `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

I have really no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The name should be projects/my-project/secrets/TELEGRAM

Comment: Thanks! Now I see it's so obvious in the docs. Duh.

Comment: How does your codebase identify itself as someone that can view your secrets? Having problems here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61301133/how-do-you-get-secrets-from-gcps-secret-manager-in-a-local-environment

Comment: Hi, I followed the instructions described here https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/quickstart

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you access a secret, you need to specify the project:

```
await secretClient.accessSecretVersion({ name: "TELEGRAM_TOKEN" })
```

should be

```
await secretClient.accessSecretVersion({ name: "projects/my-project/secrets/TELEGRAM_TOKEN/versions/latest" })
```

Comment: Obvious now looking at the docs, but doesn't help that the 'name' parameter etc are in comments and so blend in and you don't notice them in the code sample!

Comment: What does this directory refer too? It's GCloud based?

Comment: For anyone else who was lost like me, it's on the secrets manager page, under the title of the 'secret' there is a path. Such a weird way to add secrets.

Comment: now I'm being hit with Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Resource ID [projects/123123123123/secrets/mongo_uri] is not in a valid format.

Comment: do I understand correctly that if I pass secret version (number) instead of "latest" I'll get proper secret version?

Comment: @TheTanadu yes, passing in a number returns that version.

Comment: @keet-sugathadasa got me the rest of the way there. I opted to write a little helper class that handles the boiler plate for me, using the `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` environment variable to get the project ID: https://gist.github.com/battis/7ad8550cb157d7b7f320c7608099ebaf (this lets me go around writing things like `Secrets::get('API_TOKEN')` or `Secrets::get('MOTHERS_MAIDEN_NAME', 12)`

Answer (score 8):

I just encountered the same problem and I personally had to add `/versions/latest` after specifying the project name in the secret name.

```
await secretClient.accessSecretVersion({
  name: "projects/my-project/secrets/TELEGRAM_TOKEN/versions/latest"
})
```

Answer (score 6):

These answers guided me, but it took a long time for me to get this working. You need to enter the `PROJECT_ID` and not the `Project-Name`.

**Find your Project ID:**

The second column here shows the Project ID:

[image]

**Now use that and run the script**

```
await secretClient.accessSecretVersion({
  name: "projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET_NAME/versions/latest"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PROJECT_NUMBER also. After updating the PROJECT_NUMBER permission issue is resolved for me. You may also try.

"projects/<PROJECT_NUMBER>/secrets/TELEGRAM_TOKEN/versions/latest"

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to access GCP Secret Manager values using SDK or code, then you can follow the below steps:**

Step 1: Download GCP CLI

Step 2: Authenticate GCP CLI on the local machine

Step 3: Create a service using the following codes:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager').v1;


@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  async getHello(): Promise<string> {
    try {
      const secretmanagerClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
      const request = {
        name: 'projects/<YOUR_PROJECT_CODE>/secrets/<YOUR_SECRET_NAME>/versions/1',
      };
      let response = await secretmanagerClient.accessSecretVersion(request);
      response = response[0].payload.data.toString('utf8')
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log('err:', err)
    }

  }
}
```

Step 4: Run your code and call the service method.